Clementine does not play next song when logged in with another user
I've set up PulseAudio to mix sound from different users as explained in this other question, and it works for me.
But I still have one problem:

Log in with user A. Open Clementine and start playing music
Log in with user B. I hear music from user A correctly.
But when song finishes, next song in the playlist is not played.
I switch back to user A (Clementine remains open), and next song is played automatically.

I've tried Sayonara player and has the same problem (it is a Clementine fork so I guess it's normal). I've also tried Rhythmbox and I don't have this problem.
I've played with some Clementine settings but no effect.
Some tip?

I'll check behavior for Sayonara.
Btw, Sayonara is not a fork of Clementine nor of any other software.
Both players use Qt, Gstreamer and Taglib. That's all they have in common.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
